# Scheduled task with UI need delay to work properly

Tags: windows, user-interface, windows-task-scheduler

I'm trying to launch a application with a UI at login on windows, using the task scheduler. I've came across some inconsistencies with this, sometimes the UI will launch properly, other time it wouldn't. By adding a delay to the task, I can safely make it executed ON MY COMPUTER.

How can I ensure this correct behavior on any given computer?
Is it something to do with Windows UI not being "ready" or something like this?

Comment: Have you seen this post? May be help you.https://superuser.com/questions/1097766/windows-task-scheduler-run-task-if-task-isnt-running

Comment: Yes but this solution seems really hacky, it feels really strange that windows doesn't provide a direct solution

Comment: Is Task scheduler necessary? or you just want start your application on startup?

Comment: It is necessary since a regular startup will trigger UAC which is unwanted in this case

Comment: :) ok got it. I didn't have any idea except hacky things or powershell scripts. Good luck!

Comment: I'm still fuzzy on what you actually want.  Could you be more specific, what works and what does not, give us a your example?  (why you need task scheduler and e.g. the startup via shortcut is not enough?)  Do you have AD when login?

Comment: @tukan When starting a task on login, if no delay is added, this task UI sometimes does not appear (completely randomly), and if I add a delay this fix it. But I tried on different computers and this delay need to vary depending on the computer. Also, I need to start from task scheduler and not from a normal startup shortcut because in the second case, this triggers an UAC prompt that is unwanted in this situation.

Comment: @TmZn why do you use *task scheuler* for that?  Why don't you use GPO (User Configuration > Policies > Windows Settings > Scripts (Logon/Logoff),)?

Comment: I can take a look at that but I’m pretty sure it will trigger UAC was well, the only way to avoid that afaik is task scheduling